# SQL Database design for statistical analysis of many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, many-to-many

It's my first time working with databases so I spent a bunch of hours reading and watching videos. The data I am analyzing is a limited set of marathon data, and the goal is to produce statistics on each runner.

I am looking for advice and suggestions on my database design as well as how I might go about producing statistics. Please see this image for my proposed design:

[image: My Design]

Basically, I'm thinking there's a many-to-many relationship between Races and Runners: there are multiple runners in a race, and a runner can have run multiple races. Therefore, I have the bridge table called Race_Results to store the time and age for a given runner in a given race.

The Statistics table is what I'm looking to get to in the end. In the image are just some random things I may want to calculate.

So my questions are:

1. Does this design make sense? What improvements might you make?
2. What kinds of SQL queries would be used to calculate these statistics? Would I have to make some other tables in between - for example, to find the percentage of the time a runner finished within 10 minutes of first place, would I have to first make a table of all runner data for that race and then do some queries, or is there a better way? Any links I should check out for more on calculating these sorts of statistics?
3. Should I possibly be using python or another language to get these statistics instead of SQL? My understanding was that SQL has the potential to cut down a few hundred lines of python code to one line, so I thought I'd try to give it a shot with SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is fine, though Race_Results.Age is redundant - watch out if you update a runner's DOB or a race date.

It should be reasonably easy to create views for each of your statistics.  For example:

```
CREATE VIEW Best_Times AS
SELECT Race_ID, MIN(Time) AS Time,
FROM Race_Results
GROUP BY Race_ID;

CREATE VIEW Within_10_Minutes AS
SELECT rr.*
FROM Race_Results rr
JOIN Best_Times b
ON rr.Race_ID = b.Race_ID AND rr.Time <= DATE_ADD(b.Time, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);

SELECT
    rr.Runner_ID,
    COUNT(*) AS Number_of_races,
    COUNT(w.Runner_ID) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS `% Within 10 minutes of 1st place`
FROM Race_Results rr
LEFT JOIN Within_10_Minutes w
ON rr.Race_ID = w.Race_ID AND rr.Runner_ID = w.Runner_ID
GROUP BY rr.Runner_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The design of your 3 tables Races, Race_Results and Runners make perfectly sense. Nothing to improve here. The statistics are something different. If you manage to write those probably slightly complicated queries in a way they can be used in a view, you should do that and avoid saving statistics that need to be recalculated each day. Calculating something like this on-the-fly whenever it is needed is better than saving it, as long as the performance is sufficient.

2) If you would be using Oracle or MSSQL, I'd say you would be fine with some aggregate functions and common table expressions. In MySQL, you will have to use `group by` and subqueries. Makes the whole approach a bit more complicated, but totally feasible.
If you ask for a specific metric in a comment, I might be able to suggest some code, though my expertise is more in Oracle and MSSQL.

3) If you can, put your code in the database. In this way, you avoid frequent context switches between your programming language and the database. This approach usually is the fastest in all database systems.